# Passing paremeters to animation callback jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, mobile, callback

I have designed a fiddle similar to the problem I am facing in making a jQuery application.  I have multiple buttons which perform an action and must change a heading after the animation finishes.  The heading is dependent on what button was pressed.  Since you can not pass parameters to a call back I resorted to passing around a global variable.  Is there a more proper way to do so?

http://jsfiddle.net/XDdEV/

```
var heading = '';

function headingChanger(e) {
    $("#heading").html(heading);
}

$("#one").click(function (e) {
    heading = 'HEADING 1'
    $("#slider").animate({
        'margin-left' : '200px'
    },1000,'linear',headingChanger);
});

$("#two").click(function (e) {
    heading = 'HEADING 2'
    $("#slider").animate({
       'margin-left' : '0'
    },1000,'linear',headingChanger);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You could call the function as:

```
$("#two").click(function (e) {
    heading = 'HEADING 2'
    $("#slider").animate({
       'margin-left' : '0'
    },1000,'linear',function() { headingChanger(heading) });
});
```

This will make the headingChanger be evaluated on callback.

Answer (score 0):

JS is function scoped (well, what is supported also by IE8 is), therefore, you could wrap all your stuff into a nice function, and export the stuff you need globally:

```
(function headingMoverModule(exports){
    var heading = '';

    function headingChanger(e) {
        $("#heading").html(heading);
    }

    $("#one").click(function (e) {
        heading = 'HEADING 1'
        $("#slider").animate({
            'margin-left' : '200px'
        },1000,'linear',headingChanger);
    });

    $("#two").click(function (e) {
        heading = 'HEADING 2'
        $("#slider").animate({
           'margin-left' : '0'
        },1000,'linear',headingChanger);
    });
    exports.headingChanger = headingChanger;
})(window);
```

A bit of OOP-like handling helps, albeit either apply it for modules, or bind the functions to their original parameters, e.g. with [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine them and do something like:

```
function headingChanger(heading) {
    $("#heading").html(heading);
}

$("#one, #two").click(function (e) {
    var h = e.target.id==='one'?'1':'2';
    $("#slider").animate({
        'margin-left' : h=='1'?'200px':'0'
    },1000,'linear',function() { 
        headingChanger('HEADING '+h); 
    });
});
```

​

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/XDdEV/2/)